# useEffect doesn't fire when data change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, core-ui

I created a table with filter. every thing worked well.
Later on, I wanted to change the filters from material ui to Core ui.
I created one filter and tried to test it before moving. But it didn't work. The problem that useEffect doesn't fire no matter what. I even tried to put variable x and increment it when a click happen and put it as arguement in useEffect. but nothing happen.

function renderTableData(will render my table every time I pick a filter)
function onSiteChange(a function trigger when I pick a filter)
function UpdateTableData (will feed my table for the 1st time)

thank you

```js
******************************** RENDER TABLE *********************
  const renderTableData = () => {
    return (
      <div className="selectTable">
        <div
          className="ag-theme-alpine"
          style={{
            height: "75vh",
            width: "110wh",
            alignContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            alignSelf: "center",
          }}
        >
          <AgGridReact
            rowData={dataFiltred}
            rowHeight={rowHeight}
            rowStyle={{ textAlign: "center" }}
          >
            <AgGridColumn field="Pseudo"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Site"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Langue"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Actif_Inactif"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Date_Formation"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Formateur"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Nature_Formation"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Durée"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Action"></AgGridColumn>
          </AgGridReact>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  // ********************************* logic *********************

  function onSiteChange(value, type) {
    if (type === "Site") {
      value.forEach((elem) => {
        rowData.forEach((data) => {
          if (data["Site"] === elem["value"]) {
            dataSiteFiltred.push(data);
          }
        });
      });
      console.log(dataSiteFiltred);
      if (dataSiteFiltred.length) {
        dataFiltred = [];
        dataSiteFiltred.forEach((elem94) => {
          dataFiltred.push(elem94);
        });
      }
    }
  }

  function updateTableData() {
    if (!dataFiltred.length) {
      rowData.forEach((elem) => {
        dataFiltred.push(elem);
      });
    }
  }
  updateTableData();

  useEffect(
    () => {
      renderTableData();
      console.log("fired");
    },
    [dataFiltred],
    [dataSiteFiltred]
  );
```

Comment: useEffect(callback, [observables]) instead of useEffect(callback, [observable1], [observable2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **You haven't used any state, or change states or props which are not causing re-render and useEffect acordingly**

You will need to have your`dataFiltred` and `dataSiteFiltred` store in a state then update it in order to cause re-rendering/useEffect.

Something like this:

```
const [dataFiltred, setDataFiltred] = useState([]);
```

and update your state like this:

```
setDataFiltred([...dataFiltred, elem94]);
```

---

### **useEffect only accept one dependency array**

So if you want to watch both arrays do this:

```
 useEffect(
    () => {
      renderTableData();
      console.log("fired");
    },[dataFiltred, dataSiteFiltred]
  );
```

**In case it does not activate useEffect after array change, you could consider use Array.length**

```
 useEffect(
    () => {
      renderTableData();
      console.log("fired");
    },[dataFiltred.length, dataSiteFiltred.length]
  );
```

Comment: This is a good correct answer. I would just suggest to not use `length` property. It is always possible that you have diferent data within the array but the length is same and so the effect will not fire. The array data, if being changed, should be an unmutated data in which case `Object.is` will deem subsequent values as different, and the effect will be fired as expected. This is in line with the general advice to not mutate data. It has great benefits and keeps guess work out.

Comment: @SEMERBENSALEM you did not store your array in a state. I updated the answer.

Comment: I saw the update now, I tested itn and it worked. I need to read my code agagin and see how the component render. Because in the previous solution ( with material ui Select ), when make a state, the data doesn't render. I did some console log and I figure out that when the useeffect run, it empty the state. I had to create a global variable.
Anyways, I'm really thankfull for your help and kindness. Sincerely

Comment: The filter worked but the main data doesn't showup anymore on table
the function updateTableData after changing it like this 
    if (!dataFiltred.length) {
      rowData.forEach((elem) => {
        setDataFiltred([...dataFiltred, elem]);
        console.log(dataFiltred);
      });
    }
it render only the last array of the dara. 
I tried to console.log(dataFiltred) inside the loop to check what's inside of it every time. I though it keeps only the last elem every time, but it shows empty array on every turn
Ill add the full code in other reply if you want to see the hooks.

Answer (score 0):

so this is the previous working code.
Basically the same

```js
useEffect(
    () => {
      renderTableData();
    },
    [dataSiteFiltred],
    [dataMonthFiltred],
    [dataLangueFiltred],
    [dataNatureFiltred],
    [dataActifInactifFiltred],
    [dataFormateurFiltred],
    [dataFiltred]
  );

  function updateTableData() {
    var localData = [];
    if (!dataFiltred.length) {
      rowData.forEach((elem) => {
        dataFiltred.push(elem);
      });
    }
    if (
      dataFormateurFiltred.length ||
      dataActifInactifFiltred.length ||
      dataLangueFiltred.length ||
      dataMonthFiltred.length ||
      dataSiteFiltred.length ||
      dataNatureFiltred.length
    ) {
      localData = [
        ...dataFormateurFiltred,
        ...dataActifInactifFiltred,
        ...dataLangueFiltred,
        ...dataMonthFiltred,
        ...dataSiteFiltred,
        ...dataNatureFiltred,
      ];
      var dataForUser = [];
      dataFiltred = [];
      var exist = true;
      localData.forEach((elem) => {
        if (site.length && elem["Site"] !== site) {
          exist = false;
        }
        if (month.length && elem["Date_Formation"] !== month) {
          exist = false;
        }
        console.log(langue);
        if (langue.length && elem["Langue"] !== langue) {
          exist = false;
        }
        if (actifInactif.length && elem["Actif_Inactif"] !== actifInactif) {
          exist = false;
        }
        if (formateur.length && elem["Formateur"] !== formateur) {
          exist = false;
        }
        if (nature.length && elem["Nature_Formation"] !== nature) {
          exist = false;
        }
        if (exist === true) {
          dataForUser.push(elem);
        }
      });
      const seen = new Set();
      dataFiltred = dataForUser.filter((el) => {
        const duplicate = seen.has(el.id);
        seen.add(el.id);
        return !duplicate;
      });
    }
  }
  updateTableData();
```

Comment: Update it in your question, not to create a new answer, mate.

Answer (score 0):

this is the full component.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  CCard,
  CFormGroup,
  CCol,
  CLabel,
  CRow,
  CCardHeader,
  CButton,
  CCollapse,
} from "@coreui/react";

// AG GRID importaion
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { AgGridColumn, AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";

import CIcon from "@coreui/icons-react";
import { freeSet } from "@coreui/icons";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function ReacpFormationV2() {
  // golbal variables
  // var dataFiltred = []; // where we will push all filtred data
  // var dataSiteFiltred = []; // contain the data filtred using site
  // var siteFilterActive = false;
  // var dataMonthFiltred = []; // contain the data filtred using Month
  // var monthFilterActive = false;
  // var dataLangueFiltred = []; // contain the data filtred using Langue
  // var langueFilterActive = false;
  // var dataNatureFiltred = []; // contain the data filtred using Nature
  // var natureFilterActive = false;
  // var dataActifInactifFiltred = []; // contain the data filtred using Actif/Inactif
  // var actifInactifFilterActive = false;
  // var dataFormateurFiltred = []; // contain the data filtred using Formateur
  // var formateurFilterActive = false;
  //filtre collapse settings
  const [collapseFilter, setCollapseFilter] = useState(false);
  const toggleFilter = (e) => {
    setCollapseFilter(!collapseFilter);
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  // hooks
  const selectInputSiteRef = useRef();
  const selectInputMonthRef = useRef();
  const selectInputLangueRef = useRef();
  const selectInputNatureRef = useRef();
  const selectInputActifInactifRef = useRef();
  const selectInputFormateurRef = useRef();

  const [dataFiltred, setDataFiltred] = useState([]);
  const [dataSiteFiltred, setDataSiteFiltred] = useState([]);
  const [siteFilterActive, setSiteFilterActive] = useState(false);
  const [dataMonthFiltred, setDataMonthFilter] = useState([]);
  const [monthFilterActive, setMonthFilterActive] = useState(false);
  const [dataLangueFiltred, setDataLangueFiltred] = useState([]);
  const [langueFilterActive, setLangueFilterActive] = useState(false);
  const [dataNatureFiltred, setDataNatureFiltred] = useState([]);
  const [natureFilterActive, setNatureFilterActive] = useState(false);
  const [dataActifInactifFiltred, setDataActifInactifFiltred] = useState([]);
  const [actifInactifFilterActive, setActifInactifFilterActive] =
    useState(false);
  const [dataFormateurFiltred, setDataFormateurFiltred] = useState([]);
  const [formateurFilterActive, setFormateurFilterActive] = useState(false);

  // data
  const dataSite = [
    { value: "Sousse", label: "Sousse" },
    { value: "Tunis", label: "Tunis" },
    { value: "France", label: "France" },
  ];

  const dataMonth = [
    { value: "January", label: "January" },
    { value: "February", label: "February" },
    { value: "March", label: "March" },
    { value: "April", label: "April" },
    { value: "May", label: "May" },
    { value: "June", label: "June" },
    { value: "July", label: "July" },
    { value: "August", label: "August" },
    { value: "September", label: "September" },
    { value: "October", label: "October" },
    { value: "November", label: "November" },
    { value: "December", label: "December" },
  ];
  const dataLangue = [
    { value: "FR", label: "FR" },
    { value: "EN", label: "EN" },
    { value: "ES", label: "ES" },
  ];
  const dataNature = [
    { value: "upport Divinatoire", label: "upport Divinatoire" },
    { value: "Commerciale", label: "Commerciale" },
    { value: "Communication", label: "upport Divinatoire" },
    { value: "Culture Générale", label: "Culture Générale" },
    { value: "Divers", label: "Divers" },
  ];

  const dataActifInactif = [
    { value: "Actif", label: "Actif" },
    { value: "Inactif", label: "Inactif" },
  ];

  const dataFormateur = [
    { value: "SEMER", label: "SEMER" },
    { value: "Houssem", label: "Houssem" },
    { value: "Mehdi", label: "Mehdi" },
    { value: "Stéphane", label: "Stéphane" },
    { value: "Bassem", label: "Bassem" },
  ];

  // ********************************* TABLE DATA *********************
  const rowHeight = 50;
  const rowData = [
    {
      Pseudo: "Voy1",
      Site: "Tunis",
      Langue: "FR",
      Actif_Inactif: "Actif",
      Date_Formation: "January",
      Formateur: "Houssem",
      Nature_Formation: "Support Divinatoire",
      Durée: "4h",
      Action: "Visulaiser",
    },
    {
      Pseudo: "Voy2",
      Site: "Sousse",
      Langue: "EN",
      Actif_Inactif: "Inactif",
      Date_Formation: "",
      Formateur: "Si SEMER",
      Nature_Formation: "Commerciale",
      Durée: "",
      Action: "troller",
    },
    {
      Pseudo: "Voy3",
      Site: "France",
      Langue: "FR",
      Actif_Inactif: "Actif",
      Date_Formation: "February",
      Formateur: "Stéphane",
      Nature_Formation: "Communication",
      Durée: "03",
      Action: "Divers",
    },
    {
      Pseudo: "Voy4",
      Site: "",
      Langue: "ES",
      Actif_Inactif: "",
      Date_Formation: "",
      Formateur: "",
      Nature_Formation: "Culture Générale",
      Durée: "",
      Action: "Divers",
    },
    {
      Pseudo: "Voy5",
      Site: "",
      Langue: "",
      Actif_Inactif: "",
      Date_Formation: "",
      Formateur: "",
      Nature_Formation: "Divers",
      Durée: "",
      Action: "",
    },
    {
      Pseudo: "Voy6",
      Site: "",
      Langue: "ES",
      Actif_Inactif: "",
      Date_Formation: "",
      Formateur: "",
      Nature_Formation: "",
      Durée: "",
      Action: "",
    },
    {
      Pseudo: "Voy7",
      Site: "",
      Langue: "ES",
      Actif_Inactif: "",
      Date_Formation: "",
      Formateur: "Mehdi",
      Nature_Formation: "",
      Durée: "",
      Action: "",
    },
    {
      Pseudo: "Voy8",
      Site: "",
      Langue: "",
      Actif_Inactif: "",
      Date_Formation: "",
      Formateur: "SEMER",
      Nature_Formation: "",
      Durée: "",
      Action: "",
    },
    {
      Pseudo: "Voy9",
      Site: "",
      Langue: "EN",
      Actif_Inactif: "",
      Date_Formation: "",
      Formateur: "Bassem",
      Nature_Formation: "",
      Durée: "",
      Action: "",
    },
    {
      Pseudo: "Voy10",
      Site: "",
      Langue: "EN",
      Actif_Inactif: "",
      Date_Formation: "",
      Formateur: "",
      Nature_Formation: "",
      Durée: "",
      Action: "",
    },
    {
      Pseudo: "Voy11",
      Site: "",
      Langue: "EN",
      Actif_Inactif: "",
      Date_Formation: "",
      Formateur: "",
      Nature_Formation: "",
      Durée: "",
      Action: "",
    },
    {
      Pseudo: "Voy12",
      Site: "",
      Langue: "FR",
      Actif_Inactif: "",
      Date_Formation: "",
      Formateur: "",
      Nature_Formation: "",
      Durée: "",
      Action: "",
    },
  ];

  // ********************************* RENDER TABLE *********************
  const renderTableData = () => {
    return (
      <div className="selectTable">
        <div
          className="ag-theme-alpine"
          style={{
            height: "75vh",
            width: "110wh",
            alignContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            alignSelf: "center",
          }}
        >
          <AgGridReact
            rowData={dataFiltred}
            rowHeight={rowHeight}
            rowStyle={{ textAlign: "center" }}
          >
            <AgGridColumn field="Pseudo"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Site"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Langue"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Actif_Inactif"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Date_Formation"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Formateur"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Nature_Formation"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Durée"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="Action"></AgGridColumn>
          </AgGridReact>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  // ********************************* logic *********************

  function onSiteChange(value, type) {
    if (type === "Site") {
      value.forEach((elem) => {
        rowData.forEach((data) => {
          if (data["Site"] === elem["value"]) {
            setDataSiteFiltred([...dataSiteFiltred, data]);
          }
        });
      });
    }
    if (dataSiteFiltred.length) {
      setDataFiltred([]);
      dataSiteFiltred.forEach((elem) => {
        setDataFiltred([...dataFiltred, elem]);
      });
    }
  }

  function updateTableData() {
    if (!dataFiltred.length) {
      rowData.forEach((elem) => {
        setDataFiltred([...dataFiltred, elem]);
        console.log(dataFiltred);
      });
    }
  }
  updateTableData();

  useEffect(() => {
    renderTableData();
  }, [dataFiltred, dataSiteFiltred]);

  return (
    <>
      <CCard>
        <CCardHeader>
          <div
            style={{
              textAlign: "center",
              fontSize: "large",
              fontWeight: "bold",
            }}
          >
            Récapitulatif de formation continue
          </div>
        </CCardHeader>
      </CCard>
      <CCard>
        <CCardHeader>
          <CFormGroup row>
            <CCol md="6">
              <CButton
                className="btn-sm"
                size="sm"
                variant="outline"
                color="info"
                onClick={toggleFilter}
              >
                <CIcon size={"sm"} content={freeSet.cilFilter}></CIcon>
                Afficher Filtre
              </CButton>
            </CCol>
          </CFormGroup>
          <CFormGroup>
            <CCollapse show={collapseFilter}>
              <CFormGroup>
                <CCol md="6 mt-1">
                  <CRow>
                    <CCol md="2 mt-1">
                      <CLabel>Site:</CLabel>
                    </CCol>
                    <CCol md="8 mt-0">
                      <Select
                        isMulti
                        name="selectSite"
                        options={dataSite}
                        ref={selectInputSiteRef}
                        onChange={(value) => onSiteChange(value, "Site")}
                      />
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow>
                    <CCol md="2 mt-1">
                      <CLabel>Month:</CLabel>
                    </CCol>
                    <CCol md="8 mt-0">
                      <Select
                        isMulti
                        name="selectMonth"
                        id="selectMonth"
                        options={dataMonth}
                        ref={selectInputMonthRef}
                      />
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow>
                    <CCol md="2 mt-1">
                      <CLabel>Langue:</CLabel>
                    </CCol>
                    <CCol md="8 mt-0">
                      <Select
                        isMulti
                        name="SelectLangue"
                        options={dataLangue}
                        ref={selectInputLangueRef}
                      />
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow>
                    <CCol md="2 mt-1">
                      <CLabel>Nature:</CLabel>
                    </CCol>
                    <CCol md="8 mt-0">
                      <Select
                        isMulti
                        name="selectNature"
                        options={dataNature}
                        ref={selectInputNatureRef}
                      />
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow>
                    <CCol md="2 mt-1">
                      <CLabel>Actif/Inactif:</CLabel>
                    </CCol>
                    <CCol md="8 mt-0">
                      <Select
                        isMulti
                        name="selectAcifInactif"
                        options={dataActifInactif}
                        ref={selectInputActifInactifRef}
                      />
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow>
                    <CCol md="2 mt-1">
                      <CLabel>Formateur:</CLabel>
                    </CCol>
                    <CCol md="8 mt-0">
                      <Select
                        isMulti
                        name="selectFormateur"
                        options={dataFormateur}
                        ref={selectInputFormateurRef}
                      />
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                </CCol>
              </CFormGroup>
            </CCollapse>
          </CFormGroup>
        </CCardHeader>
      </CCard>

      <div className="formationContinueContainer">
        {/* ********************** Table ****************** */}

        {renderTableData()}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```